# Is offline storage recommended for an app with multiple devices using Parse backend?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, local-storage, offlineapps

I'm thinking of creating a app that saves notes like the one mentioned [here](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/using-the-local-datastore)

But the app will allow only limited notes per user. Also the user can use the app on multiple devices using a the same user account ***(which is must-have feature)***. I am using the ParseUser class by Parse and I want to know if the following use case is feasible given the scenario:

> User X has 5 notes as part of the limit. He logs into device A and
>   loses internet connectivity after 10 mins. He then add 3 notes after
>   which the device is turned off. User X now logs into device B. On
>   logging in he should see only 2 note available.

Is this possible? Is there a better solution to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user adds three notes without internet and you store them in local datastore, then the user will not see them when he logs onto another device. There is no way for your Parse backend or the app on the other device to know about those 3 notes.

So, to impose a hard limit of 5 notes, you must ensure that your app can always communicate with the server when creating notes.

Think of local datastore as a convenience for the users when working with objects. Keeping a local copy is nice for being able to work with objects without network access, and to speed up app launch. But in your case, you need to make sure that for *creating* or *deleting* notes, the user must have an internet connection. All other operations can be done without.

Comment: Hi @hansomeguy, thanks for the reply. For the same useless, is this possible?: user X to add the 3 notes on device A with no network connectivity and once he gets connectivity back, it should not allow him to sync the data or prompt him to buy more capacity.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking, but if you allow the user to create messages locally when the app has no way to check with the server if they actually CAN (based on your imposed limitations), once the app does reconnect it could then check for the user limitations and then warn the user about the problem. However, I do not find this to be a very good user experience, bc you have "allowed" them to create something that turns out not to be allowed after all. It should be your responsibility to keep track of this; not your users'...